# How can I open subtabs of a tab for testing in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open subtabs of blog tabs. I try to test clickablity of all topics in blog page 
This is page's title codes

[image]

- http://prntscr.com/r8janx

here is my codes

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BlogTestEN {
//143
// /html/body/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li/a  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver",
                "C:\\\\Users\\\\Abdullah Kandilli\\\\eclipse-workspace\\\\Selenium.maven.demo\\\\chromedriver.exe");

        //Initiating your chromedriver
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.rentnconnect.com/blog");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/span[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Turkey",Keys.ENTER);
        //driver.executeScript("window.history.go(-1)");
        for(int i = 1; i<144; i+= 2) {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div["+i+"]")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.navigate().back();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }



    }
}
```

But it opens blog page and click by xpath(correctly) but tests only 1 blog tabs. I want to test all ingredients and xpaths changing by `/html/body/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div["+i+"]`  **div["+i+"]** section with for loop.

Comment: I wrote wrong driver in setProperty but ı changed the driver to chrome. Same problem. Thanks

Comment: You probably want to give something like https://github.com/seleniumQuery/seleniumQuery a shot, which makes working with the actual DOM a heck of a lot easier.